# Singleton, как лучше инициализировать поля

Tags: java, c++, шаблоны-проектирования, шаблон-одиночка

Есть некоторый класс, который удобно реализовать как *singleton*. Как лучше инициализировать его поля(информация о том как их заполнять приходит извне)?

Адекватно ли решение заставляющее клиентский код вызывать некий метод init(parameters) перед первой попыткой получить инстанс данного *singlton*-a?

Если да, то рентабельнее ли при этом инстанцировать лишь в том самом методе init или это совершенно не критично?

Comment: Неважно когда именно инициализируются поля. Важно чтобы это произошло до их использования.

Comment: Если поля как то запрашиваются извне, то можно запросить их изнутри синглтона при его инициализации.

Comment: class Singleton { private: int m_field; Singleton() { m_field = get_field_from_somewhere(); } }

Comment: @Sheridan не, это какое-то извращение, мне для этого придётся данные хранить в каком-то, скорее всего тоже, синглтоне. Степень связанности только увеличивается... Вопрос относится скорее к тому нормально ли вообще описанное и альтернативам

Comment: А, то есть данные как то сами приходят? Синглтон может инициализироваться как до прихода данных, так и после?

Comment: Нет, мне просто сейчас непонятно, что значит "информация о том как их заполнять приходит извне"

Comment: init(data) { _data = data }, _data член класса. data это, например, какая-то инфа из файла

Comment: Теперь понятно, спасибо. В целом, я стараюсь писать синглтоны без необходимости их явной инициализации. Более того, классический синглтон подразумевает доступ к объекту через статический метод класса: https://parg.co/8OP Я бы реализовал подобное либо в конструкторе синглтона (как писал ранее), либо через некий метод Singleton::Instance()->setData(data);

Comment: @Sheridan вот об этом я и спрашивал :) Нормально ли вообще будет выглядеть подобная вещь: `Singleton::Instance()->setData(data);`, вариант с конструктором мне на вид нравится меньше, слишком уж неочевидно выглядит как по мне

Comment: Думаю, да. Выглядит нормально. Раз уж синглтон держит внутри себя некие данные, приходящие извне, то вполне логично прикрутить геттер и сеттер для них.

Comment: @Sheridan спасибо за помощь:)

Comment: наверняка лучше все поля сделать открытыми со статическим размещением, так как экземпляр всего один...

Comment: А мне не нравится сам паттерн - singletone. Я всегда стараюсь управлять временем жизни объекта при помощи DI контейнера (типа Spring). Но если вот пямо кровь из носа - надо singletone, то можно же сделать себе фабрику для получения экземпляра объекта, и пусть фабрика решает, быть классу синглтоном или нет. Кажется, Блох что то такое писал в своей книжке где то вначале.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы, во избежание использования не инициализированного класса, сделал бы так.

```
class Singleton
{
  private:
    static std::unique_ptr<Singleton> instance;
    // Конструкторы и оператор присваивания недоступны клиентам
    Singleton(параметры конструктора) {...}
    Singleton( const Singleton& );  
    Singleton& operator=( Singleton& );
public:
    static Singleton* init(параметры конструктора) {
        assert(instance == nullptr);
        instance = std::make_unique<Singleton>(параметры конструктора);
        return instance.get();
    } 
    static Singleton* getInstance() {
        assert(instance != nullptr);
        return instance.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Простите, но тут умный указатель совершенно не нужен. Владение никому не передаётся, время жизни - известно. Только ради того чтобы можно было создать экземпляр класса через вызов `.get()`?

Comment: Ради того, чтобы вызвался деструктор.

Comment: А, чтобы пару лишних строк не писать - будем оверхедить в рантайме :)

Comment: Нет там никакого оверхеда в рантайме.